# How to parse several attributes of website with same class name in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I want to parse addresses from this website (https://www.conad.it/) with Pyhthon after having searched fro a CAP in the search bar and entered the result. For many CAP's there are many addresses of stores that result and I want to scrape all of them, not just the first one (which is what my code is now doing).

Here's my code so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('pathtoChrome/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.conad.it/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='javascript:void(0)']"))).click() # accept the cookies
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='location-input']"))).send_keys("11100")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class = 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block']").click()
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'col-md-8')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Which has this as final output:

```
<h3>Conad</h3><p>Frazione Condemine 84, 11010  Sarre</p><div class="extra-services extra-services-buttons extra-services-desktop extra-services-simple"><ul class="carousel-services"></ul></div>
```

I would want only the output within the `<p>` in the upper output but for all attributes within the class `'col-md-8`, so for this example of CAP also for the second address.

Optimally I want to store it in a data set which I can append over several loops of different CAP's, so something like this (which doesn't work yet..):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('pathtoChrome/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.conad.it/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='javascript:void(0)']"))).click() # accept the cookies
CAPS = ['11100']
for CAP in CAPS:
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='location-input']"))).send_keys(CAP)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class = 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block']").click()
   print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'col-md-8')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WebDriverWait()`  and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and following `xpath` option to get all p tag value in a list.

```
print([item.text for item in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'col-md-8')]//p")))])
```

Your output would be like a list.

```
['Frazione Condemine 84, 11010 Sarre', 'Grand Chemin C/c Centreville 3, 11020 Saint-christophe', "Localita' Arensod 27, 11010 Sarre"]
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot @KunduK this solves the problem without the loop! However I still run into problems if I want to loop over CAP since I will have to make this work for several city codes. Any help on that? It seems to get stuck on the second to last line where i use `.click()`.

Comment: okay I did thanks! Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65599537/how-to-parse-data-with-looping-over-search-field-and-appending-output-in-a-data

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. A few points:

- `By.XPATH, "//a[@href='javascript:void(0)']` is not a stable [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890). Instead you can use a more stable and optimized `By.XPATH, "//a[@class='cc_btn cc_btn_accept_all']` as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='cc_btn cc_btn_accept_all']"))).click()
  ```
- The texts *`Frazione Condemine 84, 11010  Sarre`* etc are within the child `<p>` tag of the `<div>`, so you need to move a step deeper.
- Again, instead of `By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'col-md-8')]"` as the `<p>` tag is always followed by `<h3>` containing the text **Conad** we can construct a more reliable locator.
- An optimized solution:

  - Using *xpath* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

    ```
    print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[contains(.,'Conad')]//following-sibling::p[1]")))])
    ```
  - Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

    ```
    print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[contains(.,'Conad')]//following-sibling::p[1]")))])
    ```