# How to parse data with looping over search field and appending output in a data set in python?

Tags: python, selenium, loops

My question is related to the previous question: [How to parse several attributes of website with same class name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65593625/how-to-parse-several-attributes-of-website-with-same-class-name-in-python/65596470#65596470)

I want to include the parsing within a loop over `cap` and append the resulting parsed text in a vector or data set at the end of the loop and then continue at the top.

My loop now looks like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('pathtoChrome/chromedriver.exe')
caps = ['11100']
for cap in caps:
   driver.get("https://www.conad.it/")
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='javascript:void(0)']"))).click() # accept the cookies
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='location-input']"))).send_keys(caps)
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class = 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block']"))).find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class = 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block']").click()
   #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class = 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block']").click()
   print([item.text for item in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'col-md-8')]//p")))])
```

The out-commented line is just another try. In both of my attempts, when I include the `.click()` command line within the loop, the CAP doesn't get answered.

It works however, if I do not loop, i.e.:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('pathtoChrome/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.conad.it/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='javascript:void(0)']"))).click() # accept the cookies
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='location-input']"))).send_keys('11100')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class = 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block']").click()
print([item.text for item in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'col-md-8')]//p")))])
```

I want to write the results in a data set or vector and then append the next round of the loop to it, something like this, which should append text to data found by typing `11100` or`11020`, but should not print anything when typing `11000`, since there is no entry for this `cap`:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('pathtoChrome/chromedriver.exe')
caps = ['11000', '11100', '11020']
data = []

for cap in caps:
   driver.get("https://www.conad.it/")
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='javascript:void(0)']"))).click() # accept the cookies
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='location-input']"))).send_keys(caps)
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class = 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block']"))).find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class = 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block']").click()
   #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class = 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block']").click() 
   print(data.append([item.text for item in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'col-md-8')]//p")))]))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try..except` block if item not found then continue the loop.

```
caps = ['11000','11100', '11020','13022']
data = []
driver.get("https://www.conad.it/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='javascript:void(0)']"))).click() # accept the cookies
for cap in caps:
   driver.get("https://www.conad.it/")
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='location-input']"))).clear()
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='location-input']"))).send_keys(cap)
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.btn.btn-default.btn-lg.btn-block"))).click()
   try:
      data.append([item.text for item in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'col-md-8')]//p")))])

   except:
       print("no data found")
       continue

print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Frazione Condemine 84, 11010 Sarre', 'Grand Chemin C/c Centreville 3, 11020 Saint-christophe', "Localita' Arensod 27, 11010 Sarre"], ['Grand Chemin C/c Centreville 3, 11020 Saint-christophe', "Localita' Perolle 21, 11024 Chatillon", 'Frazione Condemine 84, 11010 Sarre', "Localita' Arensod 27, 11010 Sarre"], ['Via Durio 26, 13019 Varallo', 'Via Brigate Garibaldi 24/a, 13019 Varallo']]
```

Comment: Dear @KunduK: It doesn't work entirely when I try with `caps = ['11000','11100', '11020', '13022']` (adding one) and checked that there should be an entry for `'13022'` but the loop doesn't return it in the `data`. It just returns: ```[['Frazione Condemine 84, 11010 Sarre', 'Grand Chemin C/c Centreville 3, 11020 Saint-christophe', "Localita' Arensod 27, 11010 Sarre"], ['Frazione Condemine 84, 11010 Sarre', 'Grand Chemin C/c Centreville 3, 11020 Saint-christophe', "Localita' Arensod 27, 11010 Sarre"]]```. Sorry for the bother..

Comment: @tiny : Can you try the updated answer and know how this goes.

Comment: it doesn't find any data, returns four times `no data` (e.g. for every element of the loop) and then returns an empty data set.

Comment: I think the problem is still with the 9th line above: `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.btn.btn-default.btn-lg.btn-block"))).click()`. The caps get written into the search field, but as this line is within the loop, they don't get searched for (the code doesn't really click the "CERCA" button). I don't know why this doesn't work within the loop, without the loop this line works.

Comment: As an alternative Can you add some sleep in between send_keys() and button click() I mean between line 8 & 9 time.sleep(3) and check if this works.

Comment: Yes @KunduK this solves the problem! Thank you so much, so is it really the case that the program was too fast for the website/browser to react on time?